# Image slider in every jQuery accordion panel

Tags: jquery, css, slider, accordion

So, I need to put an image slider in every jQuery accordion panel.
So far I've tried bxSlider and Unslider. BxSlider works only on first panel and stops working if I switch panels. Unslider collapses and doesn't show some of the pictures.

Maybe some of you have done something like that?
Any help appreciated!

My [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/es_kaija/e42ruacs/3/) with Unslider code!

Part of my code:

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>Title 1</h3>
    <div>
        some content
        <ul class="slider">
            <li><img src="img1.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="img2.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="img3.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="img4.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="img5.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <h3>Title 2</h3>
    <div>
        some content
        <ul class="slider">
            <li><img src="img1.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="img2.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="img3.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="img4.jpg"></li>
            <li><img src="img5.jpg"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if the will work with you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matt_bernhardt/E7zay/)

```
        <p>You are here: <span id="here"></span></p>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Zero</h3>
        <div class="accord">
            <div class="panel a">0</div>
            <div id="a">
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p1.jpg" alt="a1"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p2.jpg" alt="a2"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p3.jpg" alt="a3"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p4.jpg" alt="a4"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="control" data-show="a">
                <li><a class="b">back</a></li>
                <li><a class="f">fwd</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3>One</h3>
        <div class="accord">
            <div class="panel b">0</div>
            <div id="b">
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p1.jpg" alt="a1"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p2.jpg" alt="a2"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p3.jpg" alt="a3"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p4.jpg" alt="a4"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="control" data-show="b">
                <li><a class="b">back</a></li>
                <li><a class="f">fwd</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <h3>Two</h3>
        <div class="accord">
            <div class="panel c">0</div>
            <div id="c">
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p1.jpg" alt="a1"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p2.jpg" alt="a2"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p3.jpg" alt="a3"></div>
                <div class="slide"><img src="http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/images/p4.jpg" alt="a4"></div>
            </div>
            <ul class="control" data-show="c">
                <li><a class="b">back</a></li>
                <li><a class="f">fwd</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Cool, thank you! I have two questions: 1) is it possible to cycle images automatically? 2) is it possible to put pager in place of next/prev buttons? I will try to check this for my case today.

Comment: Ok, I reviewed your code and got slides to change automatically. 
Question about pager remains. Nevertheless, you are awesome :)

Comment: You can refer this link to achieve your second question too.  http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/ZbMNT/